# How would I program an algorithm to solve this puzzle?

Tags: algorithm

Need ideas on programming an algorithm to solve a particular puzzle.

Basically, the puzzle is:

There are 9 lights arranged in a 3x3 grid:
A B C
D E F
G H I
(lets say each letter represents a light)

If you turn on or off a light, the lights adjacent to it (up, down, left or right), but not diagonal, will turn on if they are are off, or turn off if they are on.
(e.g. if A is off, B is off, D is off and you turn on A, B and D will turn on as well)

If you are given a 3x3 grid with lights that are on or off arranged randomly, what would be the least number of lights you need to turn on or off, to turn off all the lights.

Comment: You should solve this on paper first before looking for a solution in Java and C.

Comment: tried setting each variable (A through I) as either true or false, and using a loop to run through, changing each to false and the other variables that are affected as well to the opposite.  But the program seems to run forever.

Comment: Tried using paper, but I think the only possible way is listing all the possible combinations

Comment: you may want to show your code.

Comment: @Draygon You should create a board at random on paper, then see which lights you need to turn on/off to get all the lights off.

Comment: @Draygon: Not every possible combinations, but every possible combinations **starting** from your initial state, going breadth-first until you find the shortest solution. See my answer - this is a classic Graph Theory Breath-first problem. If this is an assignment, your teacher will probably like this definition.

Comment: There aren't that many permutations in a full solution to this problem.  You're dealing with 2^9 possible board states, and many of them are degenerate.  There are 9 possible board positions in which you can turn off all the lights in a single move, but only 3 distinct positions.  Since there are only 3 distinct positions that can turn off in 1 move, look at the 6 distinct positions that could create the positions that you can turn off in 1 move.  Once you've done this a couple more times, you'll have figured out the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, gonna try to program this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this as a graph theory problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).

Each given state of your puzzle is a Vertice of the graph, and each light switching is an edge that takes the Graph to another state.

Given a starting state, if you expand your graph breadth-first, your will find the sortest solution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

It is beyond the scope of this answer to expand more than this. But I can point you to a python script I made to solve a similar but different 3x3 problem:

- http://www.pangasentertainment.com/rift_3x3/
- http://www.pangasentertainment.com/rift_3x3/3x3_slider_rift.py

You can study my script to see what and why it does to solve this problem, and apply the same concepts to solve your problem on whatever language you desire.

Comment: thanks a lot, I had a feeling it was going to take a long time to complete

Comment: @Draygon: this is a good assignment (if it is one), and a good opportunity for you to learn concepts that you will be able to use many times. You should happily put some hours into it.

Comment: @Dragon: And BTW, I liked your question, but you are getting downvotes  because it is not, you know, **a question**. And by asking for C or Java, it seems you want the solution ready more than a way to get there like the one I gave you. Read the FAQ, reformat your 'question', and loose the C++/Java tags.